# WriteFile writes incorrectly

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to copy a file from resources to %localappdata%. I've something like this:

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MSIE), RT_RCDATA);
HGLOBAL exeRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hrsrc);

DWORD size = SizeofResource(hInstance, hrsrc);

TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
HANDLE hfile;
if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA|CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, 0, szPath))) { 
    PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("test.exe")); 
    hFile = CreateFile(szPath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
}

LPVOID exePtr = LockResource(hrsrc);
DWORD exeWritten = 0;

BOOL writeResult = WriteFile(hFile, exePtr, size, &exeWritten, NULL);

cout << GetLastError() << endl;

BOOL closed = CloseHandle(hFile);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

I'm able to locate the HRSRC and confirm the size using SizeofResource() just fine. CreateFile is in fact creating the file and returning the handle. GetLastError() reports that there are no errors. The amount of bytes written to disk is exactly right.

The output exe however is corrupted (the version of this file is incompatible with the version of Windows... blah blah) - it's lost its icon and everything. Looking at the original and the output file [side-by-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aNhq.png) in a hex editor it appears there's random data at the start of file.

What am I missing here?

Comment: So maybe your data is incorrect?

Comment: that doesn't mean WriteFile writes incorrectly.  It means you formatted the data incorrectly.

Comment: You aren't doing any error checking

Comment: How did "exePtr" come into being and what does it contain. The problem is quite possibly outsdie of the code we can see here...

Comment: Your subject is very poor, and deserved the short but sweet: "No it doesn't." Think about it for a second: you make a post that seems to blame an error on an API used millions of times every second, across millions of computers, without a problem, and you expect an answer?

Comment: `OP checks errors incorrectly`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `LockResource` is not correct. It should be passed the HGLOBAL `exeRes` you loaded previously.

```
LockResource(hrsrc);
```

should be

```
LockResource(exeRes);
```

From the MS documentation on [LockResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> Do not try to lock a resource by using the handle returned by the FindResource or FindResourceEx function. **Such a handle points to random data.**

And as a side note, you may want to try cleaning up that loaded-and-locked resource when you're through with it.

Comment: That was it! I'm not sure I understand the last sentence though.

Comment: @WhozCraig: while it's good practice to clean up after oneself, it's not necessary with the resource functions in modern (i.e. 32-bit) versions of Windows.

Comment: @NikBougalis good point. I still have old Win16 resource management burned into the grey-matter. (yeah, been doing it *that* long; jeezors where does the time go.)

Comment: Well spotted. The lesson for @dsp_099 is that you should always do error checking. There was none at all in this code. If you had done so you'd have found the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tend to agree.